# Getting wrong type from @ngrx/entity/Dictionary

Tags: typescript, mapping, ngrx, typescript-generics, ngrx-store

I have some NGRX-based mappings as below and one of them is returning:

```
Type 'NormalizedAppState[key]' does not satisfy the constraint 'EntityState<NormalizedAppState[key]["entities"][number]>'.
   Type 'InstrumentState' is not assignable to type 'EntityState<NormalizedAppState[key]["entities"][number]>'.
     Types of property 'entities' are incompatible.
       Type 'Dictionary<IInstrument>' is not assignable to type 'Dictionary<NormalizedAppState[key]["entities"][number]>'.
         Type 'IInstrument' is not assignable to type 'NormalizedAppState[key]["entities"] [number]'.
```

**My mappings**

```
//* Minimal NGRX *//

interface DictionaryNum<T> {
    [id: number]: T | undefined;
}
class Dictionary<T> implements DictionaryNum<T> {
    [id: string]: T | undefined;
    // [id: number]: T | undefined; // this solves the problem
}
interface EntityState<T> {
    ids: number[];
    entities: Dictionary<T>;
}

//* *//

const featureNames = {
    instrument: 'instrument',
} as const

interface EntityStateActions<
  TState extends EntityState<TState['entities'][number]>
> {}

interface IInstrument {}

interface InstrumentState extends EntityState<IInstrument> {}

abstract class NormalizedAppState {
  [featureNames.instrument]: InstrumentState;
}
```

**Error**

```
export type NormalizedFeatureActions = {
  [key in keyof typeof featureNames]: EntityStateActions<
    NormalizedAppState[key] --> The error happens here
  >;
};
```

The error goes away if I change the `Dictionary<T>` class from

```
class Dictionary<T> implements DictionaryNum<T> {
    [id: string]: T | undefined;
}
```

to

```
class Dictionary<T> implements DictionaryNum<T> {
    [id: number]: T | undefined;
}
```

But I don't want to change a third party class. And using my own Dictionary would also be problematic, as it would be necessary to replace several other types.

**How can I get rid of this error?**

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFkEsDtIWwIYBtQDkDiAlAGqAsAFCEwAuApgE4BmCAxmaACKS0mQD20CFAnqgK5wAPABUAfKADehULNABtSABMAXKGiCARpQC6akaAA+oftCVkqMMkoDchAL6FaSBAGdXTFm07ceoifAADkhkcGTQJB7MrBxcvALC4lIycoqqoK4kFDAA5nqgBsam5pbQ1nYEcqAgCspqGnDaFPmFJmYWVrbVYCQAFpAeruxIAG5kHn0MgRTsmiFwDsQRlDT0oACiEZAkPADKJAjk-smVcsqu9VqU8joVVeFsbONq0d5xfuIVjkQEIIROnEyoCoZEO-AoZFQCDCHgAvCcqjBMhRBA81AByJFZVERdEAGgcoDcoFogJI-wIpBWdAYm0eewO5AAgjFAUIUiJ9ocGGQAB7kMweOnbBnc0Rc8jydEPbaQcbonTyBpNHRiQgSSTfJbkag00AASX10GROJIUi1lOWurWRpNYQiEp5-PCSiFWx2jqEhuN2PtJA1FoQmmRdDNzjcHlQ7AoiCQkAAXtYmYFAo6EQoQWCIVCYQA6LEov35W2+h6Or4UvmBaNmnaBBhRmPIBPWABioJI4LILLecPT8gA1mQeKAYKAhzx2FRQHWyFPgR2uznxvlhR7Gd3Wcb2adZI3Yy2lMnUxvB8OdCkxF8bEA)

Comment: Are there any problems if you use `interface EntityStateActions<TState extends EntityState<any>>`? https://tsplay.dev/oN5yBN

Comment: I was just trying to avoid using any. But I restructured my code to not depend on indexes like `NormalizedAppState[key]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to put more parameters in my interfaces, so that they didn't need to access the type through the index.

```
interface EntityActions<TEntity,TState extends EntityState<TEntity>>{}

abstract class AppState {
  [featureNames.instrument]: InstrumentState;
}

export type FeatureActions = {
  [featureNames.instrument]: EntityActions<IInstrument,InstrumentState>
};
```

[Solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFkEsDtIWwIYBtQDkDiAlAGqAsAFCEwAuApgE4BmCAxmaACKS0mQD20CFAnqgK5wAPABUAfKADehULNABtSABMAXKGiCARpQC6akaAA%20oftCVkqMMkoDchAL6FaSBAGdXTFm07ceoifAADkhkcGTQJB7MrBxcvALC4lIycoqqoK4kFDAA5nqgBsam5pbQ1nYEcqAgCspqGnDaFPmFJmYWVrbVYCQAFpAeruxIAG5kHn0MgRTsmiFwDsQRlDT0oACiEZAkPADKJAjk-smVcsqu9VqU8joVVeFsbONq0d5xfuIVjkQEIIROnEyoCoZEO-AoZFQCDCHgAvCcqjBMhRBA81AByJFZVERdEAGgcoDcoFogJI-wIpBWdAYm0eewO5AAgjFAUIUiJ9ocGGQAB7kMweOnbBnc0Rc8jydEPbaQcbonTyBpNHRiQgSSTfJbkag00AASX10GROJIUi1lOWurWRpNYQiEp5-PCSiFWx2jqEhuN2PtJA1FoQmmRdDNzjcHlQ7AoiCQkAAXtYmYFAo6EQoQWCIVCYQA6LEov35W2%20h6Or4UvmBaNmnaBBhRmPIBPWABioJI4LILLecPT8gA1mQeKAYKAhzx2FRQHWyFPgR2uznxvlhR7Gd3Wcb2adZI3Yy2lMnUxvB8OdCkxF8KhSQGBdsN%20G9tdS1mueD3Yq4d7IRO%20CacnIbqAfICq6GzuqKRx-pBaoEAGFJBiGrAki47igMeabSKc8iZp22bQuM%20Y%20oWDzFiRprlosPxVjWM48PWoDtlmm69qA8LYbIuGLgReYFqaq6QZ%20bLenaDx4iWpEOhucH2DYQA)